# index expression is not of type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting the following error on `window['SERVER_DATA']`

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

```
const initialState = Object.assign(window['SERVER_DATA'] || {}, {
  auth: authState
});
```

Anyone got any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`window` does not have a property named `SERVER_DATA` do you can't use the string `'SERVER_DATA'` to index `window` (`window` does have a numeric index, hence the error).

You can add the property using augmentation:

```
declare global { // this line is necessary only if you are a module
    interface Window {
        SERVER_DATA: unknown 
    }
}
```

Or you can cast `window` to something indexable with a string: `(window as Record<string, unknown>)['SERVER_DATA'] || {}`

You can use a more specific type instead of `unknown`